# Are there other finite element types besides the usual?

Tags: finite-element-method, meshing

By finite element type I specifically mean element geometry.

I am aware of Beam/Strut, Quad, Tri, Tet & Hex but are there other types, eg a hexagonal prism, rhombihedral etc.. ?

Comment: In my experience, no. You have listed every type I've come across. What do you perceive the benefit might be for other types? How does this compare to second (or higher) order elements of the more established types? https://cdn.comsol.com/cyclopedia/finite-element-method/geometry-and-nodes-second-order-elements.png

Comment: I'm interested in what the shape functions would look like

Comment: there are only classical continuum mechanics shape functions for 2d quad and triangle shapes. By extension to 3d we get tet and hex(brick) and triangular prizms.  A "rhombihedral" element is just a hex isnt it? ...Throwing beams into the question opens another can of worms, there are all knids of structural elements, springs, and so forth.. This question is really too broad.

Comment: The question is specifically about different geometries. A rhombi-dodecahedral element would have 12 faces not 6 but would also have the space filling property of hex elements.

Comment: Surely the need for additional required computing power would quickly outstrip any potential benefits. K.I.S.S.

Comment: understood about geometry. Classical continuum finite elements are *strictly* limited to *exactly* two plane shapes (quadrilateral and triangle) and 3d constructions based on those. (and quadratic shapes based on those constructions) This is because there do not exist shape functions that exactly satisfy continuity for any other geometry. If you mean to open the question to non-classical there are boundless possibilities.

Comment: yes non-classical, thats the point of the question & yes there are boundless possiblities, I'm interested in which possibilities have been actualized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain geometries can benefit from polyhedral elements or elements with edge degrees of freedom.  I can think of three main developments in that direction:

1) Voronoi cell finite elements, e.g., https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0045794994904359

2) Isogeometric elements, e.g., https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782504005171

3) Finite elements based on exterior calculus, e.g., https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/acta-numerica/article/finite-element-exterior-calculus-homological-techniques-and-applications/1A2AEB067BCA561D9ED6D674026539B9

These elements are still being actively designed, but attention today is mostly on isogeometric and exterior calculus-based elements; primarily based of meshing issues and the need to solve multiphysics problems and to avoid element locking.